# How can I tell a script is running under cron?

Tags: bash, cron, shell

Is there a standard way to know if a shell script is running under cron as opposed to running from the command line. i.e. I'm thinking of running with more verbose output when manually kicked from the command line and enabling some features that only run when under cron.

Comment: Hello Stuart. I'm sure you've already tried it but would it be possible to differentiate using the user id?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't and there shouldn't be a difference in how a script runs, as that would make debugging nigh impossible rather than easier . Simply build in support for a debug flag or similar if you want an easy way to increase verbosity e.g. support a `-v` flag with `getopts`

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html

Comment: Is output from the "tty" command different?

Comment: @HBruijn, excellent suggestion. If verbosity should be the default, add a `-q` option for running quietly.

Comment: Verbosity was just one of the uses I was thinking of...

Comment: Could you add some logging in your script, then tail -f that log while the script is being ran via cron?

Comment: I added that there are other features that I want to run only when under cron. For implementation, it might be better to explicit enable these features via the command line but my question is whether you can tell if you are under cron.

Answer (score 1):

Since posting the question I have found the same question answered on Stack Exchange:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46789/check-if-script-is-started-by-cron-rather-than-invoked-manually